# Exchange 2010 logs

Tags: exchange-2010, database-backup, log-files

Exchange 2010 sometimes doesn't delete its logs after full backup completion!

Usually, we we just delete these logs (and we didn't face any problem because of that)

However; is there another way to force log truncation -cleanly and safely; without having to perform another backup (Other than enabling Circular Logging) ?

Comment: Turn on circular logging for the mailbox database, although that's generally frowned upon.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for your suggestion. I did think of enabling circular logging but this will bring me the risk of not being able to do recovery except up to latest backup only.

Comment: You asked `is there another way to force log truncation -cleanly and safely; without having to perform another backup?` - Enabling circular logging is the only way to do that without taking a backup.